# Multithread performance drops down after a few operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, computer-vision

I encountered this weird bug in a c++ multithread program on linux. The multithreaded part basically executes a loop. One single iteration first loads a sift file containing some features. And then it queries these features against a tree. Since I have a lot of images, I used multiple threads to do this querying. Here is the code snippets.

```
struct MultiMatchParam
{
    int thread_id;
    float *scores;
    double *scores_d;
    int *perm;
    size_t db_image_num;
    std::vector<std::string> *query_filenames;
    int start_id;
    int num_query;
    int dim;
    VocabTree *tree;
    FILE *file;
};

// multi-thread will do normalization anyway
void MultiMatch(MultiMatchParam &param)
{
    // Clear scores
    for(size_t t = param.start_id; t < param.start_id + param.num_query; t++)
    {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < param.db_image_num; i++)
            param.scores[i] = 0.0;

        DTYPE *keys;
        int num_keys;

        keys = ReadKeys_sfm((*param.query_filenames)[t].c_str(), param.dim, num_keys);

        int normalize = true;
        double mag = param.tree->MultiScoreQueryKeys(num_keys, normalize, keys, param.scores);

        delete [] keys;
    }
}
```

I run this on a 8-core cpu. At first it runs perfectly and the cpu usage is nearly 100% on all 8 cores. After each thread has queried several images (about 20 images), all of a sudden the performance (cpu usage) drops drastically, down to about 30% across all eight cores.

I doubt the key to this bug is concerned with this line of code.

```
double mag = param.tree->MultiScoreQueryKeys(num_keys, normalize, keys, param.scores);
```

Since if I replace it with another costly operations (e.g., a large for-loop containing sqrt). The cpu usage is always nearly 100%. This MultiScoreQueryKeys function does a complex operation on a tree. Since all eight cores may read the same tree (no write operation to this tree), I wonder whether the read operation has some kind of blocking effect. But it shouldn't have this effect because I don't have write operations in this function. Also the operations in the loop are basically the same. If it were to block the cpu usage, it would happen in the first few iterations. If you need to see the details of this function or other part of this project, please let me know.

Comment: Your code contains a bunch of stuff that is probably irrelevant while other parts are missing. Extract a mimal example, as per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: How about using a profiler to check what's going on there?

Comment: A profiler should help narrow this down. But given the nature of the behavior, it seems like there's a thread lock somewhere with more time being spent in the lock the longer this code runs, leading to more contention and reduced cpu usage the longer it runs. So I'd look for a shared resource/lock somewhere with more work being accumulated while inside the lock the longer this runs.

Comment: As for the tree being non-blocking, that's not necessarily true if it's thread safe for both read and write. In that case, even straight reading could involve a lock around the entire tree (not a very efficient multithreaded design for a tree, but not _that_ uncommon). If that is the case, it might be worth keeping a separate copy of the tree per thread (if that's cheap enough).

Answer (score 0):

Use std::async() instead of zeta::SimpleLock lock

Comment: This lock is our own implementation which has nothing to do with this performance drop. Even if I comment the 'lock' part (write to a file), the cpu usage will still drop drastically after a number of iterations.